# iOS 7.1.2 RESideMenu crash on +[UIView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:]: unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, residemenu

I have added `RESideMenu` library in my `iOS` project from https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu . It works fine on `iOS` 8,9 but crashing on `iOS` 7.1.2.

The issue is :

```
+[UIView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3c265a78
Sep 21 14:48:37 iPhone HafiziQuran[476] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3c265a78'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x30e6af83 0x3b61bccf 0x30e6e823 0x30e6d203 0x30dbc768 0xa0eb1 0xa5e93 0x336f7587 0x336f6edb 0x336f156b 0x3368d6e9 0x3368c851 0x336f0ca9 0x35ca5aed 0x35ca56d7 0x30e35a67 0x30e35a03 0x30e341d7 0x30d9eebf 0x30d9eca3 0x336efed1 0x336eb14d 0x782a1 0x3bb28ab7)
```

My implementation on `appdelegate` is :

```
self.dmVC=[[DEMOFirstViewController alloc] init];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.dmVC];//[[DEMOFirstViewController alloc] init]

self.leftMenuViewController = [[DEMOLeftMenuViewController alloc] init];
self.rightMenuViewController = [[DEMORightMenuViewController alloc] init];

self.sideMenuViewController = [[RESideMenu alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.navigationController
                                                                leftMenuViewController:self.leftMenuViewController
                                                               rightMenuViewController:self.rightMenuViewController];

self.sideMenuViewController.menuPreferredStatusBarStyle = 1; // UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
self.sideMenuViewController.delegate = self;
self.sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
self.sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowOpacity = 0.6;
self.sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowRadius = 12;
self.sideMenuViewController.contentViewShadowEnabled = YES;
self.window.rootViewController = self.sideMenuViewController;
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: May be because there is no such method in IOS 7.1.2?

Comment: try adding exception breakpoint, you might get some important lead there.